# Can't omit `self` when using bracket method in a class

Tags: ruby

1. I know we can define `[](arg)` in ruby class as bracket method
2. I know we can omit `self.` when calling instance method inside the class

But the following wouldnt work:

```
class Example

  def [](position)
    ...
  end

  def test(position)
    if [position] == 3 # doesn't work
  end

end
```

I know it's probably because [position] might refers to creating an array with position, but is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

This is because, as you suspect, `[]` is notation for "create array" as well, so from a syntax perspective it won't work. Ruby's parser can only tolerate so much ambiguity before it behaves unpredictably.

You must make it an explicit method call, like `self[...]`, to differentiate between the two cases.

Your `if` condition translates to "if an array containing `position` is equal to `3`...".

You can imagine that if `[x]` always made a method call to `self[x]` if you had `[]` defined as a method then it'd be really frustrating to make arrays in that code.

While there's no `{}` method, a similar ambiguity arises when using those braces:

```
p { x: y } # => Syntax error, expecting block
p({ x: y }) # => Hash argument
p { x } # => Block argument
```

Comment: thx, that's my guess as well. but wonder if this limitation of shorthand is documented somewhere for Ruby

Comment: The ISO Ruby Language Specification contains a specification of ISO Ruby's syntax.